# Crosswalk - SSL Certificate Error Alert

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-gradle-plugin, crosswalk-runtime

I'm using *Crosswalk* with graldes.

When i'm trying to load `https` from XWalkView, I'm getting a *SSL Certifcate Error Alert*.

I heard solutions working with Cordova that you need to edit files but, not even possible since I get  my dependencies from gradles here:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:11.40.277.6'
}
```

I also see that you could, with past version, override a Client, but it seems not to work with my version, and i don't want to get past version.

How can I resolve this SSL error?

Comment: Did you find the issue?